# Indenting if and else statements in python

Tags: python, if-statement

How do I indent the if else statement in python? I wrote a basic program to find the prime number in a given range. The code below correctly displays the list of prime numbers, however if the if and else are indented equally, I get a wrong list. what is going wrong?

```
for q in range(2,101):

   for n in range (2,q):
 
      if q%n == 0:
        break
     else:
        print(q)
```

Comment: What you've posted is just broken. There is a `for`/`else` construct, but that's only a guess at it being the issue

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: The basics of indentation are in the tutorial. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming for instance. But more reading is worthwhile.

Comment: @quamrana - the question is literally how to do indentation.

Comment: @tdelaney: The OP stated `I wrote a basic program`, so I thought that they might have an idea of what indentation they wanted. Turns out I was wrong.

Comment: I had never actually run across the for/else clause before. Thanks for showing me something new, @powerplay

Comment: @quamrana doesn't matter anyway. As of typing this, the answer gets 3 upvotes regardless

Comment: @Keon If for...else is new to you, you might also be interested in try...except...else

Answer (score 3):

In this case you want [the `else` to go with the `for`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html), and indented as such -- i.e. the `else` block executes if the `for` loop completes without being terminated early using a `break` statement:

```
for q in range(2, 101):
    for n in range(2, q):
        if q % n == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(q)
```

If any number `n` is a factor of `q` then the `break` will be reached.  If not, then `q` is prime, and will be printed.

(Incidentally, not the most efficient prime number checker, but never mind.)

Comment: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html for more overview of the for-else clause

Comment: @Keon Thanks for the link. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: thanks, just asking, how does one do it more effciently?

Comment: @powerplay Well for starters you are testing all the way up to `q-1` when you only need to go as far as the square root. Secondly, you are testing every integer `n`, when apart from 2 you only need to test odd numbers.